# How can I use postgresql to sort a query with a custom sort order on a string?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sorting

I have a table `incident` that has a `status` that is a string.

I want to query all incidents with a custom sort order.

A status can be one of the following: `inProgress`, `completed`, `canceled`

I want to be able to have a sort that is custom. Let the client specify the sort order. I am having problems with the query itself though.

I've tried a few things:

```
SELECT * 
FROM incident as i 
ORDER BY array_position(array["inProgress", "completed", "canceled"], i.status)

SELECT * 
FROM incident as i 
ORDER BY case when status = "inProgress" then 0
         case when status = "completed" then 1
         case when status = "canceled" then 2
              else 3
```

I get the error `Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: column "inProgress" does not exist` on all of my attempts.

I'm expecting `inProgress` to be a value of `status`, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-conditional.html) for the right sintaxis. And text use single quotes. Double quotes is for fieldnames

```
ORDER BY case 
              when status = 'inProgress' then 0
              when status = 'completed' then 1
              when status = 'canceled' then 2
              else 3
         end
```

Comment: You cant be getting the same error because if use single quotes you dont have inProgress field. Check again.